# Why can't I add a product?

Tags: services, commerce

I need to add product via services, but I have strange issue with a price field.

The case is that all fields saved correctly except price field amount and it returns:

> The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred (0): Unable to get the data property amount as the parent data structure is not set.

The url which is used: `endpoint/product`.

Here is the code:

```
fields `$node_data = array(
  'sku' => 'sku1',
  'title' => 'product title',
  'type' => 'product',
//  'commerce_price_amount' => array('amount' => 122.000, 'currency_code' => 'KWD'),
  'commerce_price_amount' => 12.000,
  'commerce_price_currency_code' => 'KWD'
); 12.000,
  'commerce_price_currency_code' => 'KWD'`
```

which successfully added all fields except price.

I think it relate to price field format.

Comment: Try using a GET call with Firefox Poster (or Chrome's Postman) to retrieve a product through Commerce Services. That will reveal to you the structure of the product, which should help you build the structure to POST.

Answer (score 0):

It works with me after disable some modules related to commerce like payment, order, cart, tax and then clear cache products saved.

I still didn't know the reason for that error